# Changing ThemeResources dynamically in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an UWP App in which I want to allow the user to change the AccentColors while using the App. For this, I would like to override the SystemAccentColor.
I noticed that I can override it in the App.xaml, but I don't know how I would do this while the programm is running.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#107C10</Color>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Most answers to this question I've found used the Theme (Default, Dark, Light) to do this. I would like if the user could change the Theme from Light to Dark Mode **AND** have a own AccentColor. The Theme change works. Changing the Accent Color as above also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [**ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#look-up-resources-in-code) official document, you could edit `SystemAccentColor` ResourceDictionary content in the code behind. But we need place the code in the [`Application.OnLaunched`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched) method

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0)); // green
        this.Resources["brush"] = brush;
        // … Other code that VS generates for you …
    }
}
```

If you want to make it change at real time, we suggest use setting class to achieve

**for example**

```
public class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush accentColor = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red);
    public SolidColorBrush AccentColor
    {
        get { return accentColor; }
        set { accentColor = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:Setting x:Key="Setting"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>


<Button
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Background="{Binding AccentColor, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Setting}}"
    Click="Button_Click"
    Content="Click" />
```

**Update the value at runtime**

```
((Setting)Application.Current.Resources["Setting"]).AccentColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige) ;
```